# Difference between 'new BehaviorSubject' and 'BehaviorSubject.create'

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am using Angular 2 and RxJS 5.

Is there any difference between these two:

And which should be used first? Thanks

```
isOpen$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

and

```
isOpen$ = BehaviorSubject.create(true);
```

Comment: Java, but the same principles likely apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046877/consider-providing-static-factory-methods-insteads-of-constructors

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede thanks for help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/BehaviorSubject.ts) doesn't have a `create` method, so I am guessing that is being exposed by the [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts) base class.

*Use the constructor*.
You should be using the constructor of the `BehaviorSubject` in this case. The `create` method is used to combine an `Observer` and `Observable`.

For instance, you could convert a `WebSocket` into a `Subject` by doing:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket(url);

var observer = Observer.create(next => webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(next)));
var observable = Observable.fromEvent(webSocket, 'message', m => JSON.parse(m.data));

var subject = Subject.create(observer, observable);
```

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be exactly the same on `Subject`. However, on `BehaviorSubject` there is no `create` method. It's inherited from `Subject`

Here is the code from [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts)

```
static create: Function = <T>(destination: Observer<T>, source: Observable<T>): Subject<T> => {
  return new Subject<T>(destination, source);
};

constructor(protected destination?: Observer<T>, protected source?: Observable<T>) {
  super();
  this.source = source;
}
```

On [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/BehaviorSubject.ts), it's probably just not yet implemented. May be will be implemented in the future.

So, in `BehaviorSubject` the behavior of `create` is totally different from the constructor.