# Access H2 connection across classes

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx, connection-pooling, h2

I'm trying to avoid static and Singletons while integrating a local [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database into my JavaFX app (Java8). Five other classes (including Controllers) require access to the database so I'm trying to share the one H2 connection between them all. I've read a [Connection Pool](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcConnectionPool.html)  avoids unnecessary reconnects, but am confused if it's applicable here. Desktop use, single user.

The following `ExtrasDB` Class contains 3 methods, `initializeDB`, `getDBValues` and `performQuery`. Previously these methods were `static` and I would call them from other classes using `ExtrasDB.getDBValues()` and use the result accordingly, but since my application uses *multiple threads* I'm looking for a better approach. I'm in the process of removing all static/Singleton use from my app.

The `initializeDB` method creates the connection and creates a table if necessary, and this method is called only once from my main controller's `initialize` method. This causes the connection `conn` to be isolated to that instance and not accessible to other class's calls on `getDBValues` or `performQuery` which causes null result sets. How do I make the database connection accessible to all necessary classes, so that these classes can freely access the database using the methods above?

```
public class ExtrasDB {

    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:~/mainDB";
    final String USER = "test";
    final String PASS = "test";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    String myStatement;
    ResultSet rs;
    DatabaseMetaData meta;

    public void initializeDB() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected to database successfully...");
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            meta = conn.getMetaData();
            rs = meta.getTables(null, null, "EXTRAS", new String[]{"TABLE"});  // <--- Checks for existence of table "EXTRAS"

            if (!rs.next()) {

                System.out.println("Table doesn't exist yet... Creating...");
                sql = "CREATE TABLE EXTRAS " +
                        "(column_1 VARCHAR(255), " +
                        " column_2 VARCHAR(255))";

                statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void getDBValues() throws SQLException {
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM EXTRAS");
        while (rs.next()) {
            //..... do something
        }
    }

    public void performQuery(String query) {
        try {
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `org.h2.test.jdbcx.TestConnectionPool` is an example.

Comment: 'performQuery(...) { executeUpdate(...); }` Mmm... what? Querying  a database results in an update? Maybe if `ResultSet performQuery() { return this.conn.executeQuery(...); }` you don't actually need to share the connection and still get results?

Comment: @trashgod, I wanted to spend time understanding *[that example](https://github.com/pkouki/recsys2015/blob/master/h2/src/test/org/h2/test/jdbcx/TestConnectionPool.java)*, and it seems the `testKeepOpen()` method demonstrates how only `man.dispose()` closes the pool, however I'm confused about: (1) Should my class `ExtrasDB` be `public static ...`and what about the 3 methods, `public` or `private`? The reason I ask is (2) My other classes either can use `ExtrasDb.getDBValues()` (static) but if I instead create a ExtrasDB object in each class, it's creating a new ConnectionPool. How to share one?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, Yes, it should be `executeQuery`, my bad. But I'm confused by your proposed solution, are you saying to replace my current `performQuery` method with `ResultSet performQuery() { return this.conn.executeQuery(...); }` How do I call this from other classes/controllers? Is this thread-safe/practical? Does it need to be a `public` or `private` method? Thanks for any feedback

Comment: How did the controllers call it without my suggestion? Was it thread safe?

Comment: The second paragraph of my original question says how I previously used `ExtrasDB.methodName();` since the `ExtrasDB` class was static, but the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431863/6867589) says this is wrong. So I tried creating a ExtrasDB object using `ExtrasDB extrasDB = new ExtrasDB` in each of the classes that requries DB access, but this creates 5 separate objects, all with different connection pools. I need to use **one** connection pool across all of my classes, without making it static or using a Singleton.

Comment: @MM88: Maybe a static factory, examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13046877/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options if you don't want some sort of static access:

1. Create a Service-Factory instance (not static) at the start up of your Program. The Service-Factory is a pojo-class containing all dependencies you want to share across other classes. Those dependencies could be created by the Service-Factory or could be set with setters. All classes which needs some dependencies you only have to offer the Factory instance.
2. You could use some framework which implements automatic dependency injection. With such a framework you only have to annotate your constructor or fields. See [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DependencyInjection/article.html) for further information about dependency injection and [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html) about how to use the spring framework for dependency injection.

In my JavaFX-App im using the first option. I have a class named Root and create an instance of it within the javafx.application.Application::start function. Some dependencies are created by the Root class and some others like (e.g. the controller instances) are set using setters. Because I'm loading my controllers via fxml-loader, I cant use the constructor to offer the Root instance, but instead every controller has a init function

```
public void initialize(Root root);
```

If you need more help. Feel free to comment this answer.